# How to remove VBA scripts from word 2010 documents?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office, add-in

I have some .dot files that I'm using as templates for a while.
They used to have VBA scripts to do some stuff and I started to replace those VBA scripts with Add-ins.

What happens is that the macro menus are still there. I tried to remove the VBA scripts (using alt+f8 and even alt+f11) but the custom menus are still there!

How do I exactly remove those VBA scripts and menus from my .dot files?

I am using Microsoft Word 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the menus were linked to the macros only. The macroes were removed, but the menus weren't.

Just clicked with the right button and removed the menus, that solved the issue. It doesn't seem to have any macro anymore.